# Creating a docker-compose.yaml file for php composer manager

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Сan someone explain what exactly command: install means in below compose.yaml file:

```
composer:
    image:composer/composer
    volumes:
      - ./document_root:/var/www/html
    command: install
```

Comment: which compose version are you referring to?

Comment: compose version 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find Command doc [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v1/#command)

as per doc it overrides the default command `command: bundle exec thin -p 3000` and executes whatever command you give in that filed.